# Alternative for tkinter's askopenfilename

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter, file-browser

Currently I am using `tkinter`'s `askopenfilename` in a quicklist editor for Ubuntu to get a file's name and location. Although it works fine, the look and feel is not native.

Is there an easy alternative dialogue window, to navigate and get a file's name and location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Zenity

Zenity's [File Selection Dialog](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/file-selection.html.en) provides an easy and natively looking solution with the `--file-selection` option. The dialog provides a number of options.

See also [Zenity's man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/zenity.1.html).

In its simplest form:

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

try:
    file = subprocess.check_output(["zenity", "--file-selection"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    print(file)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
```

#### Gtk's FileChooserDialog

Another option is [Gtk's FileChooserDialog](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html), which produces, as one might expect, perfectly natively looking file chooser dialog windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with wxPython FileDialog:

```
>>> import wx
>>> d = wx.FileDialog(None)
>>> d.ShowModal()
5101
>>>
```

It gives a more OS specific look

wxPython is arriving soon to py3k as the Phoenix project and there are already snapshots for windows and mac (see my comment below). If you want something more stable you can use pyQt `QtGui.QFileDialog`.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Dialog(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        print filename

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = Dialog()
```

You have a more complete example [here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/dialogs/).

Comment: Thanks! but I forgot to say I am using python3, and I understand wxPython is not yet available?

Comment: That depends. If you are on windows or darwin there are already snapshots for py3k ([project phoenix](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/))

Comment: Please is the answer is useful you should accept the question