# Can i use Nautilus File Manager when do filedialog.askfilename()

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, nautilus

I have a question. I'm developing a small tkinter app and I wanted to know if it was possible to integreate **Nautilus file manager** as a file manager when I use this instruction in my code:
`filedialog.askopenfilename()`

Comment: [Use this, it'll open a window as if you were selecting files to upload from your computer to a web browser page!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535339/20986448)